# Insert date in to database from dd/MM/yyyy formatted string

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

In windows form I have `DateTimePicker` with custom format `dd/MM/yyyy`.

I want to insert the selected date to `SQL Local DB` but it throwing an exception.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

my question is:
How to insert this date into a database in any format.

Here is my code

```
string query = "Insert into myTable Values('" +  dateTimePicker1.Text + "');";
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: You should learn how to use a parameterized query. With that approach you pass the date not the string representation of a date subject to globalization conventions

Comment: The database doesn't care about formats.  You just store the date.  Formatting occurs when the date is presented to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateTimePicker.Value` instead of `DateTimePicker.Text`. If you only want the date part, you could use `DateTimePicker.Value.Date`.

[`DateTimePicker.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value) is the actual `DateTime` object assigned to the control, whereas [`DateTimePicker.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.text) is the `Value` property with formatting applied. Using `Value` directly saves you from having to convert the `Text` to a `DateTime` first.

You should also use a parameterized query, as others have noted.

```csharp
string query = "Insert into myTable Values (@myDate)";
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("myDate", dateTimePicker1.Value);       
    }
}
```